# golang (*interface{})(nil) is nil or not?

Tags: go

the code snippet is the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    a := (*interface{})(nil)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(a), reflect.ValueOf(a))
    var b interface{} = (*interface{})(nil)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b), reflect.ValueOf(b))
    fmt.Println(a == nil, b == nil)
}
```

the output like below:

```
*interface {} <nil>
*interface {} <nil>
true false
```

so `var interface{}` is different from `:=`,why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

according to [golang faq](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error)

> Under the covers, interfaces are implemented as two elements, a type and a value. The value, called the interface's dynamic value, is an arbitrary concrete value and the type is that of the value. For the int value 3, an interface value contains, schematically, (int, 3).
>
> An interface value is nil only if the inner value and type are both unset, (nil, nil). In particular, a nil interface will always hold a nil type. If we store a nil pointer of type *int inside an interface value, the inner type will be *int regardless of the value of the pointer: (*int, nil). Such an interface value will therefore be non-nil even when the pointer inside is nil.

`a := (*interface{})(nil)` is equal with `var a *interface{} = nil`.

but `var b interface{} = (*interface{})(nil)` , mean `b` is type `interface{}`, and `interface{}` variable only `nil` when it's type and value are both `nil`, obviously type `*interface{}` is not `nil`.

Comment: Nice answer, did not know this. I have to say, I had a hard time understanding your explanation... You could quote the first two paragraphs from your link, it will add value to your answer!